# qq plot in R to check normality of the distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I have been reading a tutorial from https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/anova-in-r/ on how to perform ANOVA test in R. However, my question is regarding checking normality of the distribution in general.

There is an option to do a QQ plot with the ggqqplot function. However I do not know how to define the function. From what I can see in the tutorial on the datanovia, they use residuals from the linear model:

```
# Build the linear model
model  <- lm(weight ~ group, data = PlantGrowth)
# Create a QQ plot of residuals
ggqqplot(residuals(model)
```

Then I performed the same test this way:

```
ggqqplot(PlantGrowth, "weight")
```

I expected to see the same result; however, the results differ.

From the documentation of the function ggqqplot it is not clear to me how is it correct to define it. Does someone have an explanation?

Thanks :D

Comment: Linear regression has 5 assumptions one of them is that the residuals/errors should follow normal distribution therefore the `ggqqplot(residuals(model))` code is used. However,`ggqqplot(PlantGrowth, "weight")` gives the result for weight variable normality check. This is the reason you are seeing different result.

Answer (score 0):

You would just do `ggqqplot(PlantGrowth)` as long as that variable is a vector of numeric values. the function only takes a vector of numeric values and gives you [something like this](http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggqqplot-1.png) ex: `ggqqplot(iris$Sepal.Length)`